# Como posso mudar de cena na Unity mantendo tadas as caracteristicas e valores atuais do meu player?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Boa tarde. Estou com um projeto na Unity em C# pra praticar aqui, e estou com a seguinte dificuldade: Meu player vai ter algumas variaveis bool e um inventario de itens que eu preciso manter ao trocar de cenas. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?
Tipo, preciso que o player seja literalmente "transferido" para a outra cena, exatamente como ele estava na cena anterior. Não posso so instanciar o prefab do player como ele era quando foi criado.
Obrigado.

Comment: Use isto, ele não vai se destruir quando você mudar de cena
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html